# my app get crash but nothing get shown other than the line that dataformatter is not available temporarily what should i do now?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-leaks, crash

i am developing  simple game application just using pan gesture and cgaffinetransform rotate
application getting crash at unpredictable time  and console is displaying the following line
how Could i Overcome this problem? it is also show the memory waring lavels though  i am releasing every things

> Program received signal:  “0”.
>
> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys,
 I Have OverCome My Problem With The Help Of This method

```
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super DidreceiveMemoryWarning]
//I Have release All The object Here and It Work For me 
}
```

It Work Great NO Crash Issue Is Remain...

Comment: Yep I had figured it was a memory issue. Glad to see you found a way to fix your crash. Yes you ALWAYS have to catch the memory warnings like that in every view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I've encountered this it has been memory related. Basically, at some point during the rotation, there is a memory spike and the app is crashing. I had a similar issue on an app I'm working on that had a large UIScrollView. I was trying to scroll and zoom in a view that was way too big.

Is your game view very large? Like many times the size of the iphone/ipad screen? If so, you will need to make it smaller or load it in segments somehow.

Without seeing your code or knowing more information about the problem, it's hard for me to give you good advice on how to fix it, but Program received signal: “0” is definitely a memory error so that's where you can start looking. In my case I found that during a redraw of a view's layer (using setNeedsDisplay) there is a big memory spike during the draw somewhere in Apple's methods that is proportional to the size of the view. I assume there could be a similar memory spike in your case. Also, when it happened to me, I was using Instruments to try and track memory usage and the spike never showed there, it would crash before it could report the memory usage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: should i have to remove all the allocation spike from the  instrument    is it so that all alliocation spikes are  responsible for the crash of the application?

Comment: I wasn't able to ever see the spike in Instruments. That's all I was warning about. I read a lot of posts online and was able to determine that I was using too large of a view and that the memory was spiking. I lowered the size of the view and voila, no more crash. If you are trying to scroll through a large level or something, I think you're going to have to load it in segments, or switch to using opengl or something like that. Like I said, without knowing more about your app, it's hard for me to give specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

GDB and valgrind are your best bet.

Comment: thank you for reply can you explain little bit more i didn't get You

Comment: can u suggest the area where i should take care ?